# React Native: How to resolve peer dependency conflicts when a library doesn't depend on a high enough version?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, peer-dependencies

I'm using `react-native@0.64.3` which depends on `react@17.0.1`, and trying to use [this package](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker) which depends on `react@16.13.1`. When I run `npm i` it gives me this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: InTow@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.13.1" from react-native-orientation-locker@1.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-orientation-locker
npm ERR!     react-native-orientation-locker@"^1.4.0" from the root project
```

My understanding is that the version `react@16.13.1` that `react-native-orientation-locker` is using isn't high enough to satisfy the `react@17.0.1` that `react-native@0.64.3` uses. How can I work around this?

Comment: You could "override" hits behavior with ```npm install  --legacy-peer-deps```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same behavior:

Try running:

`npm install  --legacy-peer-deps`

Then:

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

and then

`npm install`